# Joists to binder - best way to attach

Tags: joists

I am planning to fit some binders to support sagging ceiling joists and want to know the best way to join the joists to binders.

The joists are C16 4x2 and span over 4 meters! The house was built in the 60ies and the sagging has caused the ceiling to crack right down the middle. Its a small crack but it is developing.

There is a binder that runs half way over the existing joists but it does not look like it was fitted properly as some joists are not attached to it (I can see gaps) and one end of it does not rest on the load bearing wall.

I am planning to run 2 additional 4x2 binders and just want your opinion on the best way to attach them to the joists.

I am thinking about using these (in order of preference)

1. Stainless Steel Banding 20mm - Run under the joist and then twist and wrap around and over the top of the binder and screw.
2. Angle brackets
3. Truss clips
4. Skew screwing from the joists to the binder.

Loft is used for light storage and is boarded.

Thanks!

Comment: I’m guessing a “binder” is like a winch or come-along, right?

Comment: ... or perhaps a beam perpendicular to the joists? (A diagram would really help here.)

Comment: Binder is usually run across joists to prevent sagging.  See this diagram https://www.carryduffdesigns.co.uk/contents/en-us/ceiling-joists.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use hurricane ties, they're intended more to hold things down than hold things up but I'm sure they'd work.

A pair of these:
[image: Simpson H2.5A]

Or one of these:
[image: Simpson H1]

Comment: Do these work for steel?

Comment: @LeeSam, they do make them for steel:  http://embed.widencdn.net/pdf/plus/ssttoolbox/fxotoivdlh/C-CF-2017-p262-264.pdf